# Profile/Debug APK

Tags: android

After I open the "Profile / debug APK" at the Android Studio for my apps, I found out there is a list of the properties. When I check other's apk, there is none like my apps. Should I care about it or not?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these libraries are from third parties, therefore should be considered as "outside of your responsibility" and most likely, their `Manifest.xml` does not even have attribute `android:debuggable="true"`.

since you demand "official sources", have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-debugger), which only confirms what I've wrote:

> However, you need to make sure you’re using an APK with [debugging enabled](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html#enable-debug).

Comment: Should I concern or not? If I ignore about it, does it will effect the security, performance and so on?